# JSON.stringify returns [] when converting object to json

Tags: javascript, json

I am struggling to create a JSON object to send over the wire. The Array in question looks like this in the Chrome debugger.

```
event: Array[0]
        $$hashKey: "02Q"
        bolFromDB: 1
        bolIndoor: null
        classId: 41
        curValue: "7.1000"
        curWeightHeight: ""
        datDate: "2013-01-13T01:00:00.000Z"
        exists: true
        id: "10"
        idClass: "W"
        idEvent: "60M"
        length: 0
        ownEvents: true
        ownSex: true
        pbs: undefined
        selected: true
        strAdditional: ""
        strName: "60m"
        strTown: "Stadtallendorf"
__proto__: Array[0]
```

*This is a small part of a much bigger object array, but in trying to break the problem down to it's smallest part, this appears to be the end of the line.*

When calling `JSON.stringify(event)`, the value returned is `[]`.

I expected `{$$hashKey: "02Q",bolFromDB: 1, bolIndoor: null, ... etc }`

Comment: It would help if you could show us how `event` is created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `event` object was initialised as an Array and was then assigned alphanumeric keyed properties. JavaScript Arrays will accept non-numeric keys, but the JSON parser will ignore these, because JSON has to use square bracket notation for Arrays and as such the numeric keys are implicit — it's impossible to express named properties using square brackets notation.

[Zach L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363701/zach-l) wrote a couple of tests to validate this assertion:

```
var test = [];
test.prop = 'foo';
console.log(test);   // [prop: "foo"] 
test                 // []
JSON.stringify(test) // "[]"
```

That's JSON showing an empty Array. However, when we start with an object:

```
var test = {};
test.prop = 'foo';
console.log(test);   // Object {prop: "foo"}
test                 // Object {prop: "foo"}
JSON.stringify(test) // "{"prop":"foo"}"
```

From what you're saying, it looks like it was never intended for `event` to be an Array, so I'd suggest you make sure to instantiate as an object before all these properties are assigned to it:

```
var event = {};
```

Comment: feel free to grab my examples below and append to your own answer if you feel its relevant and adds to yours. That way all info can be in a single canonical answer, and I can remove mine.